# How to force re render when an array changes its value in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, render

How to force re-render when an array changes its value in ReactJS.

I have an array like

```js
const [providers, setProviders] = useState<Array<any>>(props.filters?.providers!);
```

and when I call a delete function to remove one element of this array the view doesn't render.

```js
let OnDelete = (prop: any, func: any, p: IFilter) => {
    const index = prop.findIndex((x: IFilter) => x.code == p.code);
    if (index !== -1) {
        prop.splice(index, 1);
    }
    func(prop);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `setProviders` within the delete to see if that helps?

Comment: Just create a new array. It expects a new reference `setProviders [...providers] /* or */ setProviders(Array.from(providers))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a workaraund when I want the page to render againg when using hooks that works for me.

I Just declare a state and then change its value to force re-render, something like this

```
const [providers, setProviders] = useState<Array<any>>(props.filters?.providers!);
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState<boolean>(false);

const OnDelete = (prop: any, func: any, p: IFilter) => {
    const index = prop.findIndex((x: IFilter) => x.code == p.code);
    if (index !== -1) {
        prop.splice(index, 1);
    }
    func(prop);
    setRefresh(!refresh) //**Here i force a re render when changing th state**
}
```

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: There's really no need for another hook call